# is there any way to fix the gsap start trigger problem?

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap, scrolltrigger

// this is my gsap horizontal scroll code ,
// the problem is that when I start scrolling, the start trigger automatically goes down to the bottom of page 3.
// I have explicitly set it to the top of page 3, but it automatically moves down to bottom.

```
gsap.to(sections, {
  xPercent: -100 * (sections.length - 1),
  ease: "none",
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".page3",
    markers: true,
    start: "top top",
    pin: true,
    scrub: 1,
    snap: 1 / (sections.length - 1),
    end: () => "+=" + (document.querySelector(".carousal-container").offsetWidth - window.innerWidth),
    id: "carousal",
    pinSpacing: false,
  }
});

// here is my HTML snippet

<div class="page3">
    <div class="carousal-container">
        <div class="container-image">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com" alt="">
        </div>   
        <div class="container-image">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com" alt="">
        </div>       
        <div class="container-image">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com" alt="">
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

## please help me to solve this issue..